# term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Can someone explain why I am getting:

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

for the line:

```
DoSomething->*pt2Func("test");
```

with this class

```
#ifndef DoSomething_H
#define DoSomething_H

#include <string>

class DoSomething
{
public:
    DoSomething(const std::string &path);
    virtual ~DoSomething();

    void DoSomething::bar(const std::string &bar) { bar_ = bar; }

private:
    std::string bar_;
};

#endif DoSomething_H
```

and

```
#include "DoSomething.hpp"

namespace
{

void foo(void (DoSomething::*pt2Func)(const std::string&), doSomething *DoSomething)
{
    doSomething->*pt2Func("test");
}

}

DoSomething::DoSomething(const std::string &path)
{
    foo(&DoSomething::bar, this);

}
```

Comment: Haven't you mistyped this line: `void foo(void (DoSomething::*pt2Func)(const std::string&), doSomething *DoSomething)`? Shouldn't it contain `DoSomething* doSomething`? That is, the last 2 words switched?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Problem #1:** The name of the second argument and the type of the second argument are swapped somehow. It should be:

```
      DoSomething* doSomething
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
//    Type name    Argument name
```

Instead of:

```
    doSomething* DoSomething
```

Which is what you have.

**Problem #2:** You need to add a couple of parentheses to get the function correctly dereferenced:

```
    (doSomething->*pt2Func)("test");
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Eventually, this is what you get:

```
void foo(
    void (DoSomething::*pt2Func)(const std::string&), 
    DoSomething* doSomething
    )
{
    (doSomething->*pt2Func)("test");
}
```

Comment: "live example" goes to a scam site